# Cutting polygons into mutually similar and non-congruent pieces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, tiling, scissors-congruence

It is well-known that a square can be cut into a finite number of squares all of mutually different sides (hence mutually non-congruent) - for example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square

Questions:

1. Is there a non-rectangular, non-parallelogram polygon P that can be cut into a finite number of scaled down copies of P such that each copy is of a unique size (unique scale factor)?
2. Is there a convex polygon P that can be cut into a finite number of (not necessarily convex) pieces all of which are mutually similar and of different sizes to one another but are **not** similar to P?

**Remark:** As has been pointed out by M Winter in comments below, one can cut a right triangle into 2 pieces similar to itself and non-congruent to each other with the altitude falling on the hypotenuse. This gives a simple answer to question 1 and naturally gives an equally simple answer to qn 2 - indeed, one can cut a rectangle into 3 right triangles, all mutually similar and non-congruent. Are there any other answers?

**Bit added on 2nd August, 2021:** **Specific question:** Is there any *non-right* triangle T that can be tiled by finitely many mutually non-congruent triangles all similar to T? Note: It was proved by Tutte (1948) that the equilateral triangle *does not* have this property.

Comment: Parallelograms work too, but that probably isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks... made an edit to the question.

Comment: Trivial answer to 2.: a shape built from several squares, e.g. an L-shape.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, question 2 needs to be restricted to cases where P is convex. Else, as you point out, on can simply patch together squares of all kinds of different sizes into a non convex P.

Comment: An example for 1. that still might be "too simple" for you: the decomposition of a right triangle into two similar triangles that you obtain by drawing the [altitude](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)).

Comment: Thanks! Incorporated this in the question statement.