# Can a square be cut into non-right triangles that are mutually similar and pair-wise noncongruent?

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, tiling

We add a bit to [Tiling the plane with pair-wise non-congruent and mutually similar triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445805/tiling-the-plane-with-pair-wise-non-congruent-and-mutually-similar-triangles) and [Cutting polygons into mutually similar and non-congruent pieces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389303/cutting-polygons-into-mutually-similar-and-non-congruent-pieces)

A (non square) rectangle can obviously be cut into 3 mutually similar and pairwise non-congruent right triangles. And it is trivial to construct quadrilaterals formed by two similar but non-congruent and non-right triangles.

1. Can a square be cut into some finite number of triangles that are (1) mutually similar and (2) non-right? No other constraints.
2. If the answer to the above is "yes", can a square be cut into some finite number of triangles that are (1) mutually similar, (2) non-right and (3) pairwise non-congruent?

Comment: Wait, why is it obvious that a square can be cut into 3 mutually similar and pairwise non-congruent right triangles? For a non-square rectangle it is obvious, but that method does not work for the square.

Comment: thanks for the correction. edited!