# Are there rectangles that can be cut into non-right triangles that are pair-wise similar and pair-wise non-congruent?

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

We generalize the questions of [Can a square be cut into non-right triangles that are mutually similar and pair-wise noncongruent?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461297/can-a-square-be-cut-into-non-right-triangles-that-are-mutually-similar-and-pair)

1. Can any rectangle be cut into some finite number of triangles that are (1) mutually similar and (2) non-right? No other constraints. Is the answer: "some special rectangles have the property" or "none"?

Here is a more constrained version of the above question:

2. Can any rectangle (or are there some special rectangles that can) be cut into some finite number of triangles that are (1) mutually similar, (2) non-right and (3) pairwise non-congruent?